# How can I unlock screen programmatically when the notification action is clicked from lock screen in Android?

Tags: java, android

When the screen is locked and the user chooses a positive response to a notification action from the lock screen, how do I add code to prompt a screen unlock? Here is the code to my current positive notification action that i have added to the notification builder, when this action is chosen I have added an intent in the class that extends the IntentService to navigate to an activity in the app:

```
private static Action yesLetsGo(Context context) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationIntentService.class);
        intent.setAction(NotificationTasks.ACTION_YES_LETS_GO_NOTIFICATION);

        PendingIntent yesLetsGo = PendingIntent.getService(
                context,
                ACTION_YES_LETS_GO_PENDING_INTENT_ID,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Action yesLetsGoAction = new Action
                (R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,
                        "Yes Lets Go",
                        yesLetsGo);

        Log.i("Notification Utils","yesLetsGo method called");

        return yesLetsGoAction;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For enabling or disabling lock screen in Android, we need to get the instance of `KeyguardManager`

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);  
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
```

and for disabling the lock use,

```
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

And of course we need the permission in the Manifest

android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD

Comment: Hi, it was some time ago, but that is nice that it worked for you. Will you kindly accept the answer, so the others will know it works. Just hit the tick below the arrows to the left of the answer